# Revert to default github branch using Jenkins Pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a website that relies on a repo of libraries which should be contained in the project root. Both repos are stored in GitHub. I am trying to set up a Jenkins Multi-branch Pipeline for this project.

What I'm trying to so is checkout the same branch on the libraries repo as the main repo, and if a matching branch does not exist, revert to 'master'.

I've found the following in the Jenkins documentation (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#code-resolvescm-code-resolves-an-scm-from-an-scm-source-and-a-list-of-candidate-target-branch-names), which seems like it would be perfect:

```
// checkout the main source
dir('main'){
    // this will checkout the source repository that is driving the multi-branch pipeline
    checkout scm
}
// now checkout the tests
dir('tests'){
    // this will check if there is a branch with the same name as the current branch in
    // https://example.com/example.git and use that for the checkout, but if there is no
    // branch with the same name it will fall back to the master branch
    checkout resolveScm(source: git('https://example.com/example.git'), targets: [BRANCH_NAME,'master']
}
// rest of pipeline
```

However this just throws Sytnax errors (I also noticed an unclosed bracket in the example above, so tried with a closing bracket on the end, with no joy).

Here's the Jenkinsfile I've been working on:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

stages {
    stage ('Checkout') {
        steps {
            dir ('Libraries') {
                resolveScm source: github(credentialsId: '****', id: '_', repoOwner: '***', repository: 'Libraries', traits: [[$class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.BranchDiscoveryTrait', strategyId: 1]]), targets: ['does_not_exist', 'master']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the above branch name is not found, I can see that develop is, however it is not checked out. Instead whatever the last found branch was remains as the workspace (i.e. a branch that was found in a previous run).

Has anyone managed to get this successfully working?

Comment: could you add the stack trace of the error here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding 'checkout' before the resolveScm? F.e.:

```
    dir('Libraries') {
        checkout resolveScm(source: github(credentialsId: '****',
                id: '_',
                repoOwner: '***',
                repository: 'Libraries',
                traits: [[$class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.BranchDiscoveryTrait', strategyId: 1], [$class: 'WipeWorkspaceTrait']]),
                targets: ['does_not_exist', 'master'])
    }
```